# If there is no local user does my ACL need to have an OWNER@ ACE?

Tags: access-control-list

I'm setting up nfs4 ACLs on directories for users that are not local Linux users. I can use `chown 23524356:474688 dir` and that works. But what does the OWNER@ ACE represent? Is it an alias to user 23524356?